# How to hide the text when the whole page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a page that displaying a loading, my problem is when i scroll down the text is there , i need a help..

```
<h6>Hello, world!</h6>     
<div id="load_screen"> <div id="loading"> <img src="images/loading.gif"> </div> </div>
```

Here is the JS

```
<script> window.addEventListener("load", function(){ var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen"); document.body.removeChild(load_screen); }); <script>

div#load_screen{
   background: #000000;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index:10;
   position: absolute;
   margin: auto;
   left: 0; 
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}

div#load_screen > div#loading > img{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: You need to give us more to go on. How does your load_screen element look like? Can you setup a JsFiddle mimicin the problem?

Comment: Need to see styles for load_screen.

Comment: a black screen and a gif that loading in the center but when i scroll down the paragraph text is there and after loading the paragraph is show,my problem is i want to hide the paragraph text while loading @Pochen

Comment: Set then style display:none; on your paragraph to hide it in the beginning and after you remove your load_screen, set it to diplay: block, or inline or what ever your prefer?

Answer (score 0):

You could either show the text when the page has loaded or add it to the page dynamically. Here is a simple jQuery for both.

```
<div id="load_screen"> <div id="loading"> <img src="images/loading.gif"> </div> </div>
```

Then to add the content dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var title = $('<h6></h6>').html('Hello World');
    $('#load_screen').before(title);
    $('#load_screen').remove();
});
```

And to show / hide

```
<h6 id="title" class="hidden"></h6> <!-- need to make sure you have a class of hidden in css  -->
<div id="load_screen"> <div id="loading"> <img src="images/loading.gif"> </div> </div>
```

CSS `.hidden { display: none; visibility:hidden; }`

and then the jQuery will be something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#title').show();
    $('load_screen').hide();
    $('load_screen').remove(); //Or remove it
});
```

Comment: @richie please accept and upvote this answer to show that it was useful, it may help others too. Thanks